# How to sum every 2 rows in datagridview VB.net

Tags: vb.net

my question is how can I sum datetime of every 2 rows.
I found out how to count the sum the datetime but, the index of the count isnt correct
I have a datagridview with the rows

```
2022-01-29 20:30:14 
2022-01-29 19:48:37 
2022-01-29 18:02:34 
2022-01-29 16:40:33 
2022-01-29 16:06:12 
2022-01-29 14:08:27
```

This is a basicly exit \ login log , the first row is exit and the second is login and so on.
I need to figure out how much time the user was in the system in every session.
This is what I tried

```
For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count

        Dim zexit As String = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value.ToString

        Dim login As String = DataGridView1.Rows(i + 1).Cells(0).Value.ToString

        Dim sexit As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(zexit)
        Dim slogin As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(login)

        Dim span As TimeSpan = sexit.Subtract(slogin)
        DataGridView2.Rows.Add(span.Hours & ":" & span.Minutes & ":" & span.Seconds)

    Next
```

The problem is this code dont count the index correctly, basicly just need to sum by groups of every 2 rows, any suggestions?

The output is(with errros) :

```
0:41:37
1:46:3
1:22:1
0:34:21
1:57:45
```

When the correct output should be

```
   0:41:37  
   1:22:1 
   1:57:45
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that :

Don't forget to subtract 1 to DataGridView1.Rows.Count

```
For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
    ' Skip odd row
    If i Mod 2 = 1 Then Continue For

    Dim zexit As String = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value.ToString

    Dim login As String = DataGridView1.Rows(i + 1).Cells(0).Value.ToString

    Dim sexit As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(zexit)
    Dim slogin As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(login)

    Dim span As TimeSpan = sexit.Subtract(slogin)
    DataGridView2.Rows.Add(span.Hours & ":" & span.Minutes & ":" & span.Seconds)
Next
```

Comment: You can replace the last line with: `DataGridView2.Rows.Add(span.ToString("h\:m\:s"))`